# How to compute autocorrelation of signal defined by difference equations?

Tags: discrete-signals, autocorrelation

I have no experience with difference equations and I want to learn how to compute the following, but I found no resource online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Find:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[d[n]d[n + k]\right]$$

Where:

- $d[n]$ is a discrete time signal of the form:

$$d[n] = \alpha \,d[n−1]+v[n] \quad (\alpha \in [0;1])$$

- $v[n]$ is a sequence of uncorrelated zero-mean unit-variance random variables.

Comment: Hint: Your definition for $d[n]$ still works if we replace $n$ by $m=n+1$ and so you know how $d[n+1]$ relates to $d[n]$. Proceed iteratively to find $d[n+2]$ in terms of $d[n+1]$ and replace $d[n+1]$ by the just discovered formula $\alpha d[n]+\nu[n+1]$ for $d[n+2]$. Lather, rinse, repeat, working backwards to ultimately find $d[n+k]$ in terms of $d[n]$ and $\nu[n+i], 0 \leq  i \leq k$. Then substitute into $E[d[n]d[n+k]]$ and work from there.

Comment: Thanks @DilipSarwate, but it doesn't  help because I'm stuck with terms in `d[n]v[n+k]`. Even for $$\mathbb{E}[d[n]d[n+1]] = \mathbb{E}[\alpha d[n]^2 + d[n]v[n+1]]$$ I don't know how to proceed

Comment: What is $$\mathbb{E}[ d[n]v[n+1] ]$$?

Comment: Your model probably forgot to mention this explicitly or maybe you forgot to include this in your description of the problem, but it is typically assumed than the noise $\nu$ is _independent_ of the signal $d$ and so $E[d[n]\nu[m]]=E[d[n]]\cdot E[\nu[m] = E[d[n]]\cdot 0 = 0$ for all $n$ and $m$.

Answer (score 4):

There are different approaches to compute the requested auto-correlations but I would like to provide the simplest that suits to your case provided that.

- The difference equation is an LCCDE type indicating an LTI system.
- The input to the system $v[n]$ is WSS (wide sense stationary) random process.

Both of which I assume to be observed in your question. Then I would use the following well known relation between the input and output auto-correlations of an (real) LTI system driven by (real) WSS input $v[n]$:

$$ r_{dd}[k] = h[k] \star h[-k] \star r_{vv}[k] $$

where the auto-correlation of WSS $v[n]$ is $r_{vv}[k] = \sigma_v^2 \delta[k] = \delta[k]$ for an uncorrelated, zero mean, unit variance process. And $h[n]$ is the impulse-response of the LTI system signified by the LCCDE.

Then the auto-correlation sequence of the WSS output $d[n]$ is
$$ r_{dd}[k] = h[k] \star h[-k] = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} h[m]h[-(k-m)]~~~,~~~\text{ for } k = 0,\pm 1, \pm 2,... $$

So assuming that your LCCDE :
$$d[n] - \alpha  ~d[n-1] = v[n] ~~~, ~~~\text{ with } |\alpha| < 1 $$

signifies a causal LTI system, then its impulse response is:

$$ h[n] = (-\alpha)^n u[n] $$

and yields the auto-correlations to be:
$$ r_{dd}[k] = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} (-\alpha)^m u[m] (-\alpha)^{m-k} u[m-k]~~~,~~~\text{ for } k = 0,\pm 1, \pm 2,... $$

I hope you can proceed the rest.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this by trying to express $d(n)$ differently, as difference equations might be confusing. Notice that:

$$
\begin{align}
d(n)
&= \alpha d(n-1) + v(n) \\
&= \alpha^2 d(n-2) +\alpha v(n-1) +v(n) \\
&=\alpha^3 d(n-3) + \alpha^2 v(n-2)+\alpha v(n-1) +v(n) \\
&=...
\end{align}
$$

You can see from the pattern that you can express $d(n)$ as a summation:

$$d(n) =\alpha^nd(0)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha^iv(n-i)$$

where I assumed that the procces started at $n=0$. For simplicty, let me take $d(0)=0$ so that we don't have to carry that constant throughout the calculations.

Then we are left with:

$$\mathbb{E}[d(n)d(n+k)] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha^iv(n-i) \right) \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n+k-1}\alpha^iv(n+k-i) \right)\right]$$

Knowing that the noise is **uncorrelated with zero-mean**, this expression can be *really* simplified.

Notice that the expression depends on $n$ because the process is not WSS (due to the fact that I assumed that it began at $n=0$, i.e. that it hasn't been running since the beginning of times).

Comment: I haven't proof-read your answer but the last line seems to wrong, as it yields the WSS autocorrelation $r_{dd}[k]$  to be dependent on $k$ and $n$ ? $$r_d[k] = E\{ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha^i v(n-i) \sum_{m=0}^{n+k-1} \alpha^m v(n+k-m) \}$$ $$= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  \sum_{m=0}^{n+k-1} \alpha^m \alpha^i E\{v(n-i)  v(n+k-m) \}$$ $$= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  \sum_{m=0}^{n+k-1} \alpha^m \alpha^i \delta[k+i-m]$$ $$ = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha^{k+i} \alpha^i $$ $$ = \alpha^k \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\alpha^2)^i $$ $$ = \alpha^k \frac{1 -\alpha^{2n} }{1 - \alpha^2} $$

Comment: It should be independent from n

Comment: @Julien__ But it cannot, as the noise sequence $v[n]$ is assumed to start at $n=0$, instead of $n=-\infty$. If you are into computing the theoretical auto-correlation sequence $r_{dd}[k]$ of WSS $d[n]$ that would result by applying a true white noise sequence $v[n]$ (which starts at $n=-\infty$) to your LTI system, then you may better consider my answer.

Comment: I think it starts at $-\infty$

Comment: @Julien__ theoretically it should start at $n=-\infty$. But in his analysis he preferred to start at it $n=0$. Therefore the result will not be compliant with the former case.

Comment: @Julien__ Yes, I assumed the AR1 process had a finite start. Notice that if you take the limit for the process to start at $n\to -\infty$ the result is correct. I'll leave the answer as it is, as the WSS case is thoroughly covered by Fat32's answer (+1). You should accept that one as I think that's what you were looking for.

Comment: @Tendero Hi. Your derivation would also provide the same autocorrelations as $n \to +\infty$. But be careful that if you start a noise process at $n=0$, then it cannot be WSS. Which also indicates that the practical simulation of white noise is not possible. But approximations are quite good for example for $\alpha = 0.85$ then $n=200$ yields an approximation correct to 15 decimal places. (error is less than 1E-15 for 64-bit IEEE binary floating point format.)

Comment: (+1) since the beginning of times :-))